# How to open a new box when clicked on a link

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am a beginner in web developing world.

I have a table of data fetched from mysql database shown in php. Now I want to create a link on each row which on click will open up a new box (not window) of specific width-height and will show detailed information.

How can i do this ?

Comment: This is where a teacher might ask you to show your work. We're here as a resource to help you fix something that's broken, not do it all for you.

Answer (score 3):

Think you searching for modals windows.
Here is example [https://raventools.com/blog/create-a-modal-dialog-using-css-and-javascript](https://raventools.com/blog/create-a-modal-dialog-using-css-and-javascript/)

Comment: Many thanks.......i didn't knew the name to look for....this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a div with css `display:none;`, and use javascript to toggle the visiblity. That might work.